Finding the Coordinates of a Point $P$ such that the Incircles of Triangles $ACP$, $BCP$, and $ABP$ are Congruent
I have three vertices of a triangle $ A = (x_a, y_a) $, $ B = (x_b, y_b) $, and $ C = (x_c, y_c) $, and I need to find the coordinates of a point $ P $ such that the incircles of the triangles $ ACP $, $ BCP $, and $ ABP $ are congruent.

In barycentric coordinates, any point $ P $ can be expressed as:
$
P = \alpha A + \beta B + \gamma C
$
where $ \alpha $, $ \beta $, and $ \gamma $ are proportional to the areas of triangles $ PBC $, $ PAC $, and $ PAB $, respectively, and satisfy $ \alpha + \beta + \gamma = 1 $.
Now, we know that the areas of these triangles should be proportional to the semiperimeter times the inradius. If the incircles of the triangles are congruent, this gives us the relations:
$
\text{Area of } PBC \propto (a + PB + PC), \quad \text{Area of } PAC \propto (b + PA + PC), \quad \text{Area of } PAB \propto (c + PA + PB)
$
Here, $ a =BC$, $ b =AC$, and $ c =AB$ represent the side lengths of the triangle $ ABC $.
Then I define the following function for any point $ X $:
$
f(X) = w_a A + w_b B + w_c C
$
where:
$
w_a = \frac{a + XB + XC}{a + b + c + 2(XA + XB + XC)}, \quad w_b = \frac{b + XA + XC}{a + b + c + 2(XA + XB + XC)}, \quad w_c = \frac{c + XA + XB}{a + b + c + 2(XA + XB + XC)}
$
$P$ is the solution to $f(P)=P$ (it is a fixed point of the function).
However, I am stuck at this point due to the nonlinearity of the problem. The direct use of lengths complicates the calculations, leading to square roots and multiple variables in the equations. I would prefer a solution that involves other geometric properties, such as relevant angles or the inradius, which might lead to more elegant equations—even if these equations are only solvable numerically, perhaps involving trigonometric or higher-degree equations with just one variable. Could I approach this problem using such parameters to solve for $ \alpha $, $ \beta $, and $ \gamma $ instead of relying on the lengths?

Doing a $13-6-9$ search reveals that you are looking for $X(5394)$ in the Encyclopedia of Triangle Centres. Over there is listed
Barycentrics              (unknown)

…at least until I came.
Let $a,b,c$ be the side lengths and $x:y:z$ the normalised barycentric coordinates of the desired triangle centre. According to code provided there by Peter Moses, if we define
$$s_{ab}=\sqrt{(ay)^2+(bx)^2+(a^2+b^2-c^2)xy}$$
and $s_{bc}$ and $s_{ca}$ cyclically, then in addition to the obvious $x+y+z=1$ we have
$$\frac{a+s_{ab}+s_{ca}}x=\frac{b+s_{bc}+s_{ab}}y=\frac{c+s_{ca}+s_{bc}}z$$
In x5394-symbolic.py of this gist of mine I used SymPy to eliminate the square roots and $z$, obtaining two polynomials in $a,b,c,x,y$ which $X(5394)$ satisfies. These were then dehomogenised by setting $a=1$ and piped into Singular to eliminate $y$; $19$ minutes later it spat out a degree-$8$ polynomial in $x$ with polynomials in $b/a$ and $c/a$ of total degree $9$ as coefficients.

CFS = \
[[[  72,  240,  216,  -96, -264, -144, -24],
  [ 240,  368,   96, -288, -336,  -80],
  [ 216,   96, 1104,  480,   24],
  [ -96, -288,  480,  160],
  [-264, -336,   24],
  [-144,  -80],
  [ -24]],
 [[ -300, -1208, -1872,  -992,   888, 1776, 1200, 416, 84, 8],
  [-1208, -4000, -4288,  2368,  4784, 2144,  192,   0,  8],
  [-1872, -4288, -8112, -6560, -1200, -640, -336, -32],
  [ -992,  2368, -6560, -4288,    32,    0,  -32],
  [  888,  4784, -1200,    32,   504,   48],
  [ 1776,  2144,  -640,     0,    48],
  [ 1200,   192,  -336,   -32],
  [  416,     0,   -32],
  [   84,     8],
  [    8]],
 [[  353,   1859,  4248,  6112,   4034,  -2978, -7248, -4840, -1387, -153],
  [ 1859,  12264, 21224,  3568, -18418, -14680, -4768,  -896,  -153],
  [ 4248,  21224, 42796, 28996,   6736,   4912,  3756,   612],
  [ 6112,   3568, 28996, 30384,   4696,    896,   612],
  [ 4034, -18418,  6736,  4696,  -4738,   -918],
  [-2978, -14680,  4912,   896,   -918],
  [-7248,  -4768,  3756,   612],
  [-4840,   -896,   612],
  [-1387,   -153],
  [ -153]],
 [[    30,   -486,   -1480,  -7320, -17660, -11188,  11224, 17864, 7886, 1130],
  [  -486, -14960,  -36184, -27376,  17228,  30128,  20872,  9136, 1642],
  [ -1480, -36184, -110664, -93560, -17560, -13320, -15576, -3496],
  [ -7320, -27376,  -93560, -92384, -25416,  -9136,  -4520],
  [-17660,  17228,  -17560, -25416,  15380,   5244],
  [-11188,  30128,  -13320,  -9136,   5244],
  [ 11224,  20872,  -15576,  -4520],
  [ 17864,   9136,   -3496],
  [  7886,   1642],
  [  1130]],
 [[  -175,   -561,  -4164,  -5996,  15846,  35946,   7612, -25548, -19119, -3841],
  [  -561,   7800,  23316,  24888,   3498,  -2520, -20556, -27864,  -8001],
  [ -4164,  23316, 126036, 157596,  42660,  24012,  35148,  10116],
  [ -5996,  24888, 157596, 184176,  41292,  27864,  18436],
  [ 15846,   3498,  42660,  41292, -32058, -16710],
  [ 35946,  -2520,  24012,  27864, -16710],
  [  7612, -20556,  35148,  18436],
  [-25548, -27864,  10116],
  [-19119,  -8001],
  [ -3841]],
 [[  -120,   -528,    2040,   14232,   8136, -30024, -31128,  10248, 21072, 6072],
  [  -528,  -3504,   -9720,   12864,  17688, -40560, -24840,  31200, 17400],
  [  2040,  -9720,  -66960, -101136, -23016, -29592, -59904, -18912],
  [ 14232,  12864, -101136, -200736, -28776, -31200, -41568],
  [  8136,  17688,  -23016,  -28776,  77664,  37008],
  [-30024, -40560,  -29592,  -31200,  37008],
  [-31128, -24840,  -59904,  -41568],
  [ 10248,  31200,  -18912],
  [ 21072,  17400],
  [  6072]],
 [[   144,    720,   2412,  -4572,  -15012,   2484, 22212,   5868,  -9756, -4500],
  [   720,   2304,  12636, -15912,  -44748,  24912, 48708, -11304, -17316],
  [  2412,  12636,  41256,  12456,  -67140,  -7668, 69552,  28656],
  [ -4572, -15912,  12456,  82080,  -19836,  11304, 54288],
  [-15012, -44748, -67140, -19836, -119592, -61128],
  [  2484,  24912,  -7668,  11304,  -61128],
  [ 22212,  48708,  69552,  54288],
  [  5868, -11304,  28656],
  [ -9756, -17316],
  [ -4500]],
 [[    0,      0,  -1296,  -1296,  3888,  3888,  -3888,  -3888, 1296, 1296],
  [    0,      0,  -6480,      0, 19440,     0, -19440,      0, 6480],
  [-1296,  -6480, -36288, -10368, 81648, 45360, -44064, -28512],
  [-1296,      0, -10368,      0, 50544,     0, -38880],
  [ 3888,  19440,  81648,  50544, 85536, 59616],
  [ 3888,      0,  45360,      0, 59616],
  [-3888, -19440, -44064, -38880],
  [-3888,      0, -28512],
  [ 1296,   6480],
  [ 1296]],
 [[0, 0,      0,      0,      0,      0,     0,     0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0,      0,      0,      0,      0,     0,     0, 0],
  [0, 0,  11664,  11664, -23328, -23328, 11664, 11664],
  [0, 0,  11664,      0, -23328,      0, 11664],
  [0, 0, -23328, -23328, -23328, -23328],
  [0, 0, -23328,      0, -23328],
  [0, 0,  11664,  11664],
  [0, 0,  11664],
  [0, 0],
  [0]]]

CFS[i][j][k] from x5394-compute.py of the gist, reproduced above, gives the coefficient of $x^i(b/a)^j(c/a)^k$ (or equivalently $x^ia^{9-j-k}b^jc^k$).
Through numerical experiments I am almost certain that the CFS polynomial has Galois group 8T39 and thus that it splits into a quadratic and sextic over the number field generated by some quartic in $x$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Z[a,b,c]$. I am also almost certain that we can take for said quartic another polynomial provided by Peter Moses in the ETC entry:
$$64x^4-16(5s_1^2-8s_2)x^3+4(11s_1^4-36s_1^2s_2+16s_2^2+24s_1s_3)x^2-s_1(11s_1^5-60s_1^3s_2+80s_1s_2^2+48s_1^2s_3-96s_2s_3)x+(s_1(s_1^3-4s_1s_2+12s_3))^2$$
where $s_1=a+b+c,s_2=ab+ca+bc,s_3=abc$. I have not actually carried out the splitting though.

It looks like any two in-circles are tangent on the side common to them at the same point. Assuming this is true, then $ P $ would be the Fermat point of the triangle; i.e. $\angle APB = \angle BPC = \angle APC = 120$. This can be shown by drawing the angle bisectors and perpendicular from incentre to side in each of the triangles $ABP, BCP, ACP$ and proving that the six resulting triangles around $P$ subtend the same angle at $P$.
However, I was unable to prove the assumption is actually true.

A check with GeoGebra doesn't seem to confirm your assumption.
